# FormControl type angular typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have something like this

```
  get formControls(): any {
    return this.form.controls;
  }
```

But now I have a problem with `tslint`. It returns the error
**Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type.**
Does anybody knows what type does `this.form.controls` return? I have tried `FormGroup`, `FormControl`, but none was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  get formControls(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.form.controls;
  }
```

> A collection of child controls. The key for each child is the name
> under which it is registered.

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#controls

Comment: Can you please write a code answer, thanks

Comment: He did. It's exactly what you asked for - A replacement for `any`.

Comment: Can you please write code because ANY does not work

Comment: Thanks, this work, can you aslo help me with this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482989/formcontrol-type-angular-abscract-type-typescript