# FormControl type angular Abscract type typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make tslint proper return type, and have something like this

```
 get formControls(): any {
    return this.form.controls;
  }
```

It returns the error **Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type.**

In previous question
[FormControl type angular typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481053/formcontrol-type-angular-typescript#67481156)
I got answer to my question to make it like this

```
 get formControls(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.form.controls;
  }
```

It is now OK, but then I have problems with other functions inside component, because I have more get like this

```
  get addressFormControls(): any {
    return this.formControls.address.controls;
  }

  get addressFormGroup(): any {
    return this.formControls.address;
  }
```

Now I got another error **Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'**

Here is my final code, can somebody help me to write proper return type

```
  get formControls(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
    return this.form.controls;
  }

  get addressFormControls(): any {
    return this.formControls.address.controls;
  }

  get addressFormGroup(): any {
    return this.formControls.address;
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious to get an error with that.

> `AbstractControl` is the base class that `FormGroup` `FormArray` and `FormControl` extends.

`FormGroup` and `FormArray` defines `control` which is not available in `FormControl` and `AbstractControl`.

As per angular definitions, if say `form` is of type `FormArray` then `formControls()` must return `AbstractControl[]`

```
get formControls(): AbstractControl[] {
  return this.form.controls;
}
```

However if `form` is a `FormGroup` then the return type is fine as you mentioned

```
get formControls(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
  return this.form.controls;
}
```

But since `AbstractControl` does not defines `controls` we can manually typecast it to `FormGroup`. So in this case this would solve the problem.

```
get addressFormControls(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
  return (this.formControls.address as FormGroup).controls;
}

get addressFormGroup(): FormGroup {
  return this.formControls.address as FormGroup;
}
```

**Update:** I would suggest a refactor as

```
get addressFormControls(): { [key: string]: AbstractControl } {
  return this.addressFormGroup.controls;
}
```